# Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation OpenCV Kmeans

Tags: c++, memory, opencv, initialization

I'm doing a simple kmean clustering in openCV code. It runs successfully, but when I use valgrind to check it has memory problems:

> ==6982== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>   ==6982==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation

Here is the simple code, where input image 'obs' is stacked into the big matrix 'samples' then I call the kmean built in function

```
/*GETINITKMEANS: calculate initial kmeans segmentation (lev,img) 
obs:    input image
    levels: array holding intensity levels
    hh:     height
    ww:     width of image
    nlevels:number of levels

    lev:    holds segmentation labels
    img:    holds segmentation reconstruction
 */

void getinitkmeans(Mat &obs,Mat &lev,Mat &img,vector<UINT8>& levels,int hh,int ww,int nlevels)
{
    int dim=hh*ww;

    // data for kmeans
    Mat samples(dim,3,CV_32F,Scalar(0));
    Mat labels(dim,1,CV_8U,Scalar(0));
    Mat centers(nlevels,3,CV_32F,Scalar(0));

    // extract bgr pixel values into samples matrix
    for (int i=0;i<hh;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<ww;j++)
        {
            samples.at<float>(i*ww+j,0) = (float)obs.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
            samples.at<float>(i*ww+j,1) = (float)obs.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
            samples.at<float>(i*ww+j,2) = (float)obs.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
        }
    }

    // run kmeans algorithm
    kmeans(samples,nlevels,labels,cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,30,0),1,KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS,centers);

    // construct lev, img
    for (int i=0;i<hh;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<ww;j++)
        {
            lev.at<UINT8>(i,j) = labels.at<int>(i*ww+j,0);
            img.at<UINT8>(i,j) = levels[labels.at<int>(i*ww+j,0)];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem then? maybe valgrind gets confused. By the way, you could get the samples matrix in 2 lines of code using convertTo and reshape. You could greatly speed up k-means on pixels colors by running it using the image histogram, as many pixels have the same color.

Comment: This is a basis of a bigger program which crashes on memory error malloc(). So I'm trying to remove any warning from valgrind.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that? I got your point on many pixels have the same color, but how can we use the histogram instead?